# proof of convergence in distribution with random vectors

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, vectors

I'm tasked with the following true or false statement and having to prove it:

For random d × 1 vectors, $X_n$ $→_d$ X if and only if each component $X_{ni} →_d X_i$, 1 ≤ i ≤ d.

After some googling I've found that this seems to be true, however there's no clear path to proving it.

I assume starting with each component $X_{ni} →_d X_i$, 1 ≤ i ≤ d is an easier proof, however I have no idea where to begin on either side of the if and only if statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.

Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be independent uniform on $\{0, 1\}$, and $X_n = (\xi, \xi)$, $X = (\xi, \eta)$. Then each component of $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ (as it's the same distribution), but $X_n$ don't converge in distribution to $X$, because for $A = \{(x, y) | x > \frac{1}{2}, y < \frac{1}{2}\}$ (which is continuity set for $X$) we have $P(X \in A) = \frac{1}{4}$, but $P(X_n \in A) = 0$.